# Google maps API - did not accepted properly: language and region

Tags: api, location, maps, geocode

How to always receive: Warsaw ?

Warszawa VS Warsaw

```bash
$ curl -s "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Warszawa+Świętokrzyska+18&key=<MY-KEY>&region=en&language=en" | jq '.results[0].formatted_address'

"Świętokrzyska, Warszawa, Poland"



$ curl -s "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Warszawa&key=<MY-KEY>&region=en&language=en" | jq '.results[0].formatted_address' 

"Warsaw, Poland"
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the "cause" of this bug: "Localization of Street Addresses in the Google Maps APIs" https://mapsplatform.googleblog.com/2014/11/localization-of-street-addresses-in.html]  November 20, 2014.

This is bug.

Also I've reported to issueTracker https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/235460799.